# Laravel 5 retrieve user email from resetpasswordlog through hashed token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the record from resetpasswordlog (Note, I have changed the table name) table in Laravel 5.5 through the generated token during forgot password. I do not want to use the default notification and instead send email to users. I used Hash::make($token) but this is not matched with any record in the "resetpasswordlog" table.

```
// user model
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
dd(Hash::make($token));
}
```

The result is:

> $2y$10$sBeJOd33E7A10ZSwvVZpFeqNe/Cka2jYLdp4rI8fwIkgIFoJZgY5S

But in the db table, I saw the record is entered as like:

> $2y$10$v1BM7EE4Xs64Xlv8Cktz/OHpwS/KX0qpMjg4Jf.VuPg...

My intention is to get the user email through the hashed token and send email to that user.

Comment: What's the token value before hashing?

Comment: In DB before get the token: $2y$10$mj.GPulAe7LlyX//qAuHD.nqwaYOD4d.J3tUy9MdkbC...
I received the token in browser: $2y$10$v7jpSPv1wMmdMoV75RK0jOS2Qr7Yh5M6Gzc0NCTYAVHg4159pns8e
Value changed in DB: $2y$10$WUUKtwguFcxlVLcQLFBMbOZ/nn9saSwUFk6Vzz7Yxhl...

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: @ZerosAndOnes No! But I made another way and it was successful.

Comment: You may share it here and select your own answer, so that if someone in future faces the same issue, it will be helpful for them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) generates a different hash value for the same input string, as it generates a random 128-bit salt during hashing, thus, the values from `Hash::make` will not match.

Instead, you can use the [check](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.html#method_check) method to confirm if there is a match of the unhashed token with the hashed token value in database i.e.,

```
Hash::check($token, $hashedTokenInDatabase);
```

---

Also, due to the above you won't be directly able to retrieve user's email through only the token, you will require a field through which you can query the 
resetpasswordlog table to retrieve the relative hashed token value.

---

A workaround would be to extend the [DatabaseTokenRepository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/DatabaseTokenRepository.php) class and override its `getPayload` method, so that the tokens aren't hashed in the database and an email can be retrieved from the database with a matching token, i.e.,

```
return ['email' => $email, 'token' => $token, 'created_at' => new Carbon];
```

However, if security is a concern then I wouldn't suggest this approach due to the points mentioned in [Should password reset tokens be hashed when stored in a database?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86913/should-password-reset-tokens-be-hashed-when-stored-in-a-database).